# Data-price error with trailing zero's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery script that allows users to see total prices for the services they select on a form via checkboxes.

The price calculator is simple and works alright. However, whenever there is a trailing zero on the end of a price (ex. 14.90) it does not calculate and instead concats to the end of the price (rather it's default or other prices are selected). Is there another method to use in this situation?

Here is the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/tn5xtfss/

```
var base_price = 0;



function CalculatePrice() {
    var base_cost = base_price;
    $(".quote--price:checked").each(function() {
        base_cost += $(this).data("price");
    });

    $("#final_price").text(base_cost);
}

CalculatePrice();

$(".quote--price").click(function() {
    CalculatePrice();
});
```

Comment: Something like this?  https://jsfiddle.net/xby6chkg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse your number

```
 base_cost += parseFloat($(this).data("price"));
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yj52pzq6/)

Comment: That was quick and effective! Thanks! I know this wasn't apart of my original question but could you also help me with with only showing two numbers after the decimal? I get no trailing zero and if the calculation is not correct then I can get some weird reminders.